# run command in node.js gives errors

Tags: node.js

I need to run the following command in node

```
 ./Transistor --config=/your_installed_directory/etc/DEV.Transistor.cfg --instance=101 --logdir=/tmp -i
```

I get the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\vikas\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vikas\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I need to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: `no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vikas\package.json'`

Comment: @hoangdv Thanks. I created a package.json and now I'm getting this: `npm ERR! missing script: ./Transistor`. Although there is a file named transistor in it. Should I specify the start script. This is the command I'm using `npm run ./Transistor --config=/your_installed_directory/etc/DEV.Transistor.cfg --instance=101 --logdir=/tmp -i` .